# Leaking wiper fluid tank, 2000 BMW 328i

Tags: bmw, leak

I have a 2000 328i, and it cannot retain wiper fluid. Is that tank easy to replace? Do I need to be very careful with the intake hose inside the tank (is it especially fragile?)?

Answer (score 3):

The tank is not hard at all to replace, and if the hose does not appear to be dry-rotted it should be easy to removed. I recommend replacing the grommet for the fluid pump as well.